# Bean can't be autowired and return NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm developing an ERP using Spring MVC and JPA/Hibernate frameworks.
My problem is that the bean `construireBilanImpl` in the service layer can't be instantiated because the `opmanimpl` field can't be autowired and return `NullPointerException`

**com.ensi.erp.metier.CreerBilanImpl:**

```
@Transactional
@Component

public class ConstruireBilanImpl implements ConstruireBilan {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private  OperationManager opmanimpl ;

    private float immobilisations_corporelles=sommeComptes(1266,1322);
public ConstruireBilanImpl(){};
    public void setOpmanimpl(OperationManagerImpl x){opmanimpl=x;}

    public float sommeComptes(int... doubles){
        if (this.opmanimpl==null){System.out.println("BAAAAAAAAAAAAAADDDDDDDDDD");}
        return opmanimpl.sommeComptes(doubles);


    }
```

**com.ensi.dao.OperationMnagerImpl:**

```
@Component
public class OperationManagerImpl implements OperationManager {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="ERP")
        private EntityManager em;

        public OperationManagerImpl(){};

        public void setEm(EntityManager emm){em=emm;}


        public void creerOperation(opération op) {
            if (em!=null){System.out.print(" manager de bean initialisé");}

              em.persist(op);



            System.out.println("dou5oul---------2");}

        public opération rechercherOperation(int clé){
            opération oper=em.find(opération.class,clé);
            return oper;

        }

        public void supprimerOperation(int clé)
        {
            opération oper=em.find(opération.class,clé);
            em.remove(oper);
        }


        public void modifierId(int clé,int nv){
            opération oper=em.find(opération.class,clé);
            oper.setIdop(nv);
            em.flush(); 
        }
        public void modifierJournal(int clé,char j){
            opération oper=em.find(opération.class,clé);
            oper.setJournal(j);
            em.flush(); 

        }
        public void modifierCompte(int clé,int nvc){
            opération oper=em.find(opération.class,clé);
            oper.setCompte(nvc);
            em.flush(); 
        }
        public void modifierLibellé(int clé,String nvl ){
            opération oper=em.find(opération.class,clé);
            oper.setLibellé(nvl);
            em.flush(); 

        }
        public void modifierDate(int clé,Date nvd){

            opération oper=em.find(opération.class,clé);
            oper.setDateop(nvd);
            em.flush(); 
        }
        public void modifierDr(int clé,float nvdr){

            opération oper=em.find(opération.class,clé);
            oper.setDr(nvdr);
            em.flush(); 
        }
        public void modifierCr(int clé,float nvcr){

            opération oper=em.find(opération.class,clé);
            oper.setCr(nvcr);
            em.flush(); 
        }


        public List<opération> listeOpération() {
            String ss="select op from opération op";
            Query req= em.createQuery(ss);

            return req.getResultList();
        }


        public void SupprimerOpération(int ref){

            opération op=em.find(opération.class, ref);
            em.remove(op);

        }

        public float sommeComptes(int... doubles) {
            String liste= new String();
            String x;
            for (int d : doubles) {
                x=Integer.toString(d);
                x=x.concat(",");
                liste=liste.concat(x);
            }
        liste=liste.substring(0, liste.length()-1);
        String cc =" select sum(op.cr) from opération op ";
         System.out.println(cc);
            Query req= em.createQuery(cc);
            Number somme=(Number)req.getSingleResult();
            return somme.floatValue();

        }


    }
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Jun 23 20:01:45 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/C:/Users/housseminfo/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ERP_PCD/WEB-INF/classes/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5168781e: defining beans [datasource,persistenceUnitManager,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,operationmanager,opser,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,operationController,operationManagerImpl,homeController,construireBilanImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5168781e: defining beans [datasource,persistenceUnitManager,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,operationmanager,opser,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,operationController,operationManagerImpl,homeController,construireBilanImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'operationController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ensi.erp.metier.ConstruireBilan com.ensi.erp.controllers.OperationController.bil; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'construireBilanImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager com.ensi.erp.metier.ConstruireBilanImpl.opmanimpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [operationmanager, operationManagerImpl]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ensi.erp.metier.ConstruireBilan com.ensi.erp.controllers.OperationController.bil; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'construireBilanImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager com.ensi.erp.metier.ConstruireBilanImpl.opmanimpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [operationmanager, operationManagerImpl]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'construireBilanImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager com.ensi.erp.metier.ConstruireBilanImpl.opmanimpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [operationmanager, operationManagerImpl]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:873)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager com.ensi.erp.metier.ConstruireBilanImpl.opmanimpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [operationmanager, operationManagerImpl]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [operationmanager, operationManagerImpl]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:825)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 38 more
juin 23, 2014 8:01:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Grave: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'operationController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ensi.erp.metier.ConstruireBilan com.ensi.erp.controllers.OperationController.bil; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'construireBilanImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager com.ensi.erp.metier.ConstruireBilanImpl.opmanimpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [operationmanager, operationManagerImpl]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ensi.erp.metier.ConstruireBilan com.ensi.erp.controllers.OperationController.bil; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'construireBilanImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager com.ensi.erp.metier.ConstruireBilanImpl.opmanimpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [operationmanager, operationManagerImpl]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'construireBilanImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager com.ensi.erp.metier.ConstruireBilanImpl.opmanimpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [operationmanager, operationManagerImpl]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:873)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager com.ensi.erp.metier.ConstruireBilanImpl.opmanimpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [operationmanager, operationManagerImpl]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.ensi.erp.dao.OperationManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [operationmanager, operationManagerImpl]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:825)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: just curious: is that "Bean" in the title?

Comment: @AdrianShum It was until it got vandalized.

Answer (score 1):

The interface `OperationManager` might have other implementation classes also. Hence Spring would not be able to figure out which implementation has to be created. If that is the case, then the below should help. Also the interface need not be marked as a `Component`.

`@Autowired(required=true)
@Qualifier("operationManagerImpl")
private  OperationManager opmanimpl ;`

Answer (score 0):

This is Because `Spring` is not finding bean by `opmanimpl`, use

```
@Autowired(required=true)
@Qualifier("operationManagerImpl")
private  OperationManager opmanimpl ;
```

[DOC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html)

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace clearly indicates that you have multiple beans eligible for autowiring. You haven't shown your configuration, but I suspect you're using component scanning and then also explicitly defining a bean. Pick one.